# What's wrong with this statement? ( [avc oRecurrsStart.text] )

Tags: objective-c, ios7

What's wrong with this statement? (the last one) which is used in a different class (CreateRecurringAppointments).  I'm getting an error message (XCode 5.1.1 stating "Expecting ]" between *oRecurrsStart* and *text*.

```
AppointmentsViewController *avc = [AppointmentsViewController new];
NSString *sd = [avc oRecurrsStart.text];
```

This is the definition of *oRecurrsStart*, which is in the AppointmentsViewController class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *oRecurrsStart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call a method (or send a message in Objective-C terms) to and instance of object `avc` and instead of providing a name for this method - you're inserting text property of another UITextField object.

I think you need to change the line to

```
avc.oRecurrsStart.text
```

Comment: Thank you... that makes perfect sense... I appreciate your time answering this... SD

Comment: For completion, you could've also had `[[avc oRecurrsStart] text]`